# How can I make my output be printed as '+' for the number of times a letter appears in a list?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to let my code print out the number of times a letter is being printed (spaces excluded) and here is my code so far:

```
def charHistogram(filename: str):
    g = list(filename)
    f = []
    for x in g:
        f.append([x, (g.count(x)*'+')])
    return f
print(charHistogram(filename='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Praesent ac sem lorem. Integer elementum
ultrices purus, sit amet malesuada tortor
pharetra ac. Vestibulum sapien nibh, dapibus
nec bibendum sit amet, sodales id justo.'))
```

and here is my output according to the code:

```
[['L', '+'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['p', '++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['d', '+++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], [',', '++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['c', '+++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['c', '+++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['d', '+++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['p', '++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['c', '+++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['g', '++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['.', '++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['P', '+'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['c', '+++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], ['.', '++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['I', '+'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['g', '++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['c', '+++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['p', '++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], [',', '++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['d', '+++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['p', '++++++'], ['h', '++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['r', '++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['c', '+++++++'], ['.', '++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['V', '+'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['b', '+++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['p', '++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['b', '+++++'], ['h', '++'], [',', '++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['d', '+++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['p', '++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['b', '+++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['c', '+++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['b', '+++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['b', '+++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['n', '+++++++++'], ['d', '+++++++'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['m', '++++++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], [',', '++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['d', '+++++++'], ['a', '+++++++++++++++'], ['l', '++++++++'], ['e', '++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['i', '+++++++++++++++'], ['d', '+++++++'], [' ', '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'], ['j', '+'], ['u', '++++++++++++'], ['s', '+++++++++++++++++'], ['t', '++++++++++++++++++'], ['o', '+++++++++'], ['.', '++++']]
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
e ++++++++++++++++++++++++
t ++++++++++++++++++
s +++++++++++++++++
i ++++++++++++++++
a +++++++++++++++
m ++++++++++++
r ++++++++++++
u ++++++++++++
l +++++++++
n +++++++++
o +++++++++
c +++++++
d +++++++
p +++++++
b +++++
g ++
h ++
j +
v +
```

What am I supposed to change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
def armar_dict(filename: str):

    diccionario={}
 
    for letra in filename:
        if letra in diccionario:
            diccionario[letra]=diccionario[letra]+1
        else:
            diccionario[letra]=1
 
    return diccionario


def order_dict (diccio):
    sorted_dict = {}
    sorted_keys = sorted(diccio, key=diccio.get)

    for w in sorted_keys:
        sorted_dict[w] = diccio[w]

    return sorted_dict 

def char_histogram(diccio):
    for k, v in diccio.items():
        print (k + ": " + "+"*v)
```

I hope you like it.

Comment: thank u for ur response but can you do it without using 'key='?? so that like I kinda understand it too. I'm new to this so tbh, I kinda dont know many built in functions so yea, is there a way to do it without the built in function??

Comment: You can use `char_histogram(char_histogram(armar_dict(texto)))` instead of `char_histogram(char_histogram(order_dict(armar_dict(texto))))` and you shouldn't be using the key but it wont be ordered

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with:

```py
import string

def charHistogram(filename: str):
    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
    g = list(filename.lower())
    chars = set(g)
    f = []
    for char in chars:
        if char in alpha:
            f.append([char, (g.count(char)*'+')])
    f.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
    return f

result = charHistogram(filename='''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                                  elit. Praesent ac sem lorem. Integer elementum
                                  ultrices purus, sit amet malesuada tortor
                                  pharetra ac. Vestibulum sapien nibh, dapibus
                                  nec bibendum sit amet, sodales id justo.''')

for char, bar in result:
    print(char, bar)
```

Which gives:

```
e ++++++++++++++++++++++++
t ++++++++++++++++++
s +++++++++++++++++
a +++++++++++++++
i +++++++++++++++
r ++++++++++++
u ++++++++++++
m ++++++++++++
o +++++++++
n +++++++++
l ++++++++
c +++++++
d +++++++
p ++++++
b +++++
h ++
g ++
j +
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```py
replace_list = [(" ", ""), (".", ""), (",", "")]

def charHistogram(filename: str):
    for old, new in replace_list:
        filename = filename.lower().replace(old, new) # replace unwanted characters
    g = list(filename)
    f = {}
    for x in g:
        if x in f:
            f[x] += "+"
        else:
            f[x]= "+"
    return sorted(f.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) # sort

data = charHistogram(filename='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac sem lorem. Integer elementum ultrices purus, sit amet malesuada tortor pharetra ac. Vestibulum sapien nibh, dapibus nec bibendum sit amet, sodales id justo.')
for key, value in data:
    print(key, value)
```

This gives you:

```
e ++++++++++++++++++++++++
t ++++++++++++++++++
s +++++++++++++++++
i ++++++++++++++++
a +++++++++++++++
r ++++++++++++
m ++++++++++++
u ++++++++++++
l +++++++++
o +++++++++
n +++++++++
p +++++++
d +++++++
c +++++++
b +++++
g ++
h ++
v +
j +
```

Comment: that `if/else` can be replaced with one line of `f[x] = f.get(x, '') + '+'`

Comment: That's right, would make it shorter, yet I didn't want to put too much change in to keep it understandable.

Answer (score -1):

I think, my approach has lesser lines :-) , though the crust is same

```
def charHistogram(filename: str):
    filename = str.lower(filename)
    occurences = {char: "+" * filename.count(char) for char in filename  if char.isalnum()}
    occurences = sorted(occurences.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
    occurences = "\n".join([f"{l} {c}" for l, c in occurences])
    return occurences
```